# Formatting currency value with toLocaleString in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to format a double value according with toLocaleString in node.js for a firebase cloud function. This is the code I use:

```
PriceFormated = Price.toFixed(2).toLocaleString("de-DE", {style: "currency", currency: CurrencySymbol});
console.log('Price:',PriceFormated)
```

The result is:
"Price: 1984.00"

but it should be:
"Price: 1.984,00"

As a reference, please check this:
http://droidscript.org/javascript/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString().html
or
https://www.jsman.net/manual/Standard-Global-Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Is there an error in the code, or is firebase cloud functions not working as expected?

Comment: .toFixed returns a string, but you need a number to successfully use .toLocaleString.  Try getting rid of .toFixed(2), you might not even need it.

Comment: The result of "console.log('Price Test:',Price.toLocaleString("de-DE", {style: "currency", currency: CurrencySymbol}))" is "Price Test: $1,984.00"...so it still doesn't adopts the format :(

Comment: Weird, I get `Price Test: 1.984,00 $` in Chrome 59

Comment: That is what I would expect...thanks for testing